# Removing duplicate values when there's no identity column

Tags: sql

I have a temporary table which looks a little like the below:

[image: sample table data]

The SheetID and PersonIDs are unique, so by looking at the above data, you can see these are duplicates. The above is quite common in the data I'm looking at, where there are duplicate records, with the FirstName and Surname NULL. There is no ID column for the rows.

How do I remove these record(s)?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, sql-server, ...?

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: Are you looking for an `select` or a `delete` query?

Comment: You forgot to include the code from your attempt at this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete duplicates with missing names on either of the two columns, you can use:

```
delete from t
    where t.surname is null and
          (exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.sheetId = t.sheetId and t2.surname is not null
                  ) or
           exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.personid = t.personid and t2.surname is not null
                  )
          );
```

Note:  I split the exists into two clauses so the database can use indexes (if available) on `(sheetid, surname)` and `(personid, surname)`.

I am also guessing that it is sufficient to just check the surname for null-ness.